# Trying to access some properties of pivotal table, throws exceptions

Tags: c#, office-interop, pivot-table

I have xlsx file with pivotal tables, I’m using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel libraries to access the file and manipulate data. While I can read and even change some properties, others throw exceptions on access, for example, I can change slicer name, but when I try to get slicer active item:

```
Workbook.SlicerCaches.Item[1].Slicers[1].ActiveItem
```

I get:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Nieokreślony błąd. (Wyjątek od HRESULT:
>   0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

Also, ActiveFilters for my pivot tables are always null, event though table clearly have filters.

What am I doing wrong?